# AngularJS: Store failed http request and try later

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm searching for an elegant way to store http requests with AngularJS.
I'm developing a mobile app, running on Cordova / Phonegap and here we have the problem, that the network could be lost.

When a user writes a comment, but can't send it to the server, the request should be stored (I think LocalStorage would be a good place), and automatically send later when the server is available again.

I have two questions:
1. Are there any ready to use solutions for this?
2. If not, how would you design such a thing?

I already have an $http interceptor, that listens to failed requests with `state==0` and a flag set on the request side `{retry: false}`:

```
responseError: function(response) {
  // something went wrong, report to airbrake
  if(response.status==0 && response.config.retry) {
    // don't reject the response, user should see everything is ok
    // somehow here we should store the request, and try it later
    return response;
  }
  return $q.reject(response);
}
```

I would use then a service that stores the requests in LocalStorage and tries them later. But I'm not sure, if this is the right way to go, or if I'm thinking to complicated.

Comment: That seems to be the correct approach. Store the request config in localStorage and on application load send the requests one by one.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage this for storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use local storate to keep the data, with some flag to point that the data is not stored on the server.

Then, on another process or triggered by a timer or you name it, follow the next steps:

- Send data to the server
- It worked: mark the data as saved
- It did not work: try again later, show a notification (optional)

Comment: ok, thanks! Thats also the way, I was thinking to do it. Maybe out of this, I can release a bower component or sth else ;)